# How to interpret this nested boolean shorthand?

Tags: java

I do not know how to interpret this nested boolean because the !keyPart1.equals(key.keyPart1) is a comparison operator yet it's the statement if it were true.

Also, this if-else statement being nested in another if statement is confusing me. Any help would be appreciated or a break down of this code would probably clear up my misunderstanding. Thank you! :)

```
if (keyPart1 != null ? !keyPart1.equals(key.keyPart1) : key.keyPart1 != null) return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, drawing a truth table is easier said than done :) It may help to rewrite the condition on multiple lines:

```
keyPart1 != null // If keyPart is not null
    // Then the value is the negation of keyPart1.equals(key.keyPart1)
    ? !keyPart1.equals(key.keyPart1)
    // Otherwise, the value is whether key.keyPart1 is not null
    : key.keyPart1 != null
```

Comment: Hi, long overdue but thank you for the explanation <3

Answer (score 0):

So the thing is:

If the `keyPart1` is *null* then we return value of expression `key.keyPart1 != null`.

If the `keyPart1` is *not null* then we return `!keyPart1.equals(key.keyPart1)`.

`!keyPart1.equals(key.keyPart1)` is negation of comparison `keyPart1` to `key.keyPart1`

Answer (score 0):

It might also help, to extract the thing in the if, and rewrite the ? :  to an if.

So where v is the thing in the if, rewritten to an if, instead of a ? : you get

```
boolean v;
if (keyPart1 != null) {
 v=!keyPart1.equals(key.keyPart1);
}
else {
 v=key.keyPart1 != null;
}
 if(v)
  return false;
```